# How to iteratively populate values in a dataframe using conditional tests

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, data-entry

I'm trying to accomplish what I initially thought would be a simple task, but my coding skills for R are apparently very rusty. Simply put, I have a data frame set up in R, "test". X1 is a factor and X2 is a column with null values:

- **X1    X2**
- F1    .
- F1    .
- F2    .
- F3    .
- F3    .

My end goal with this program is to create a function or program that will iterate over each level of the factor, ask the user for a value with which to fill X2 over the current level of X1, and then move on to the next level of X1.

How would you program this?

My issue is coming from the loop itself. Either the loop isn't rewriting the values of X2 (doing it as a local variable I assume) or I'm getting the "condition has length >1" error. Here are a few versions that I've tried:

```
someValue<-0
for (i in levels(test$X1)){
 if (identical(test$X1,i)) {
    test$X2<-someValue}
someValue+1
}
#This doesn't seem to overwrite X2


someValue<-0
for (i in levels(test$X1)){
 if (test$X1==i) {
    test$X2<-someValue}
someValue+1
}
#This throws the 'condition has length >1' warning. I understand why this is happening. 
However, ifelse isn't an option because I want it to do nothing 
and iterate to the next level of i if false.
```

I don't want to use a lookup table or a join for this process because that would eliminate the time savings I'm trying to get by writing this. But apparently I'm pretty ill-equipped to do loops in R!

Comment: I think you want the `ifelse` function and not the `if` statement.

Comment: @Dave2e `ifelse` requires an 'if false' condition. If I'm iterating through a loop, and each level of the iteration has a unique value, what would you need to use for the 'if false' argument?

Comment: If true assign a new value, if false continue with the existing value: `test$X2<-ifelse(test$X1==i, someValue, test$X2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function does what you describe in the question:

```
fillfac <- function(vec){
    fill <- character(length(vec))

    # " iterate over each level of the factor"
    for(i in levels(vec)){ 
        #"ask the user for a value with which to fill X2"
        # "over the current level of X1"
        print(paste("What should be the fill for", i, "?"))
        value <- scan(what = "character", n=1)
        fill[labels(vec)[vec] == i] <- value
    }   

    return(fill)
}
```

Example:

```
> X1 = factor(sample(1:5, size = 20, rep=T))
> X2 <- fillfac(X1)
[1] "What should be the fill for 1 ?"
1: "one"
Read 1 item
[1] "What should be the fill for 2 ?"
1: "two"
Read 1 item
[1] "What should be the fill for 3 ?"
1: "three"
Read 1 item
[1] "What should be the fill for 4 ?"
1: "four"
Read 1 item
[1] "What should be the fill for 5 ?"
1: "five"
Read 1 item
> (df <- as.data.frame(cbind(X1,X2)))
   X1    X2
1   1   one
2   3 three
3   1   one
4   2   two
5   5  five
6   3 three
7   3 three
8   4  four
9   2   two
10  3 three
11  2   two
12  3 three
13  4  four
14  5  five
15  2   two
16  1   one
17  2   two
18  2   two
19  5  five
20  4  four
```